# how to query select from distinct from purchase_order_id column and get order by latest version

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like this:

| id | purchase_order_id | version | remarks | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 1 | new | edit |
| 2 | 24 | 2 | update | edit |
| 3 | 25 | 1 | new | confirm |
| 4 | 24 | 3 | update | confirm |

my propose is how to select query for first makesure purchase order id it is distinct and then version it is getting the latest version.
so the propose data is is like this :

| id | purchase_order_id | version | remarks | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 25 | 1 | new | confirm |
| 4 | 24 | 3 | update | confirm |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (purchase_order_id) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY purchase_order_id, version DESC;
```

[image: screenshot from demo link below]

### Demo